# how to wirte a python snippet in vscode to print something

Tags: json, code-snippets

I found that when you type`.print` at the end of the line in pycharm, it will automatically convert this line to `print(line)`. So I want to know whether vscode can achieve such a function with snippet.
I have written a snippet after googling.

```json
"print": {
        "prefix": "print",
        "body": "\nprint(${TM_CURRENT_LINE-})"
    }
```

However, there is a problem in this snippet: the prefix will be added during conversion. Besides, it only adds an additional line instead of changing the current line.
[demonstration of snippet now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PhPn.gif)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this：

```
".print": {
"prefix": ".print",
"body": ["\nprint(${TM_CURRENT_LINE/(^.+)(\\..+)/$1/g})"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: (adding $1 puts your cursor at the dollar sign position)

```
"print": {
    "prefix": "pr",
    "body": "print($1)",
}
```